# android application connect with facebook and create account

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developping an android application when the user can connect with his **facebook** account or create an application account. i want to know should i save the user information in my database when he is using facebook(i mean login with facebook). 
if i save it, and later he want to create an account with the same facebook address mail. how to treat it

Comment: Yes you can save users info from facebook server to you database and if user want to create another facebook account with same id (facebook wouldn't allow user to do that, don't worry) you can update you users info.

Comment: @nilesh virkar thank you for your answer, i'm talking when he want to create an account in my application with the same facebook address mail. here there will be 2 account with the same mail in my database. but in my database the address and username should be unique.

Comment: @juniordeveloper ok, I would recommend that you can create user account using one email id and map to users facebook id, both may be same or may be not.

Comment: @nilesh virkar i think it's a good idea, if you have an example about mapping, can you post it please, i have no idea how to use it. i'm working with mysql